# Issue in accepting dynamic input from the terminal in nodejs using process.stdin

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have been working since a long time on this issue and did surf a lot of sites but did not find a convincing answer.
Let me explain my requirement. I want to accept inputs from the terminal, use those inputs to run a set of instructions and then again accept new set of inputs from the terminal using `process.stdin` in **nodejs**.

Please find below my sample code. Kindly throw light on my mistakes and a better way to put the instructions, this would help me learn better.

```
input();
console.log("Completed 1");
input();
function input()
{
  process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');
  process.stdin.resume();
  process.stdin.on('data',function(text){
    console.log("Type: " + typeof text); 
    if(text == "quit"){
      console.log("Inside if"); 
      done();
    }
    console.log("Received: " + text);
  });
}

function done(){
  console.log("Exiting");
  process.exit();
}
```

When I run this code, if my input is "quit", this text is not being matched and doesn't enter the if condition. It continues to accept anything and everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string you entered has a new line character at the end:

`quit\n`

Providing that in your conditional will fix this issue. See this [documentation](https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/command-line/how-to-prompt-for-command-line-input/) as example.

```
input();
console.log("Completed 1");
input();
function input()
{
    process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');
    process.stdin.resume();
    process.stdin.on('data',function(text){
        console.log("Type: " + typeof text);
        if(text === "quit\n"){
            console.log("Inside if");
            done();
        }
        console.log("Received: " + text);
    });
}

function done(){
    console.log("Exiting");
    process.exit();
}
```

Edit: To address your second concern, see the documentation for process. The solution is clear. Hand a call back to the 'exit' event. Only synchronous code is allowed in that callback.

```
function input() {
    process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');
    process.stdin.resume();
    process.stdin.on('data',function(text){
        console.log("Type: " + typeof text);
        if(text === "quit\n"){
            console.log("Inside if");
            done();
        }
        console.log("Received: " + text);
    });
    process.on('exit', (code) => {
        console.log('got to it');
    }); }
```

Comment: This solution is working.But then this is still behaving asynchronous. As I mentioned earlier, I want a line by line code execution. PFB output

    **deepak@deepak-VirtualBox:~/Desktop$ node test.js  
    Completed 1  
    hey  
    Received: hey  
      
    Received: hey  
  
    quit  
    Inside if  
    Exiting**

I have removed this line of code "console.log("Type: " + typeof text);"
How do I achieve synchronous execution without using other packages??

Comment: Considering the call back you suggested, plse refer to the code snippet in the ques. **1.** Am calling the input(). This needs to be completely executed only then the inline console statement should be printed(or any business logic). **2.** As per the solution you suggested, if I have a callback in the input(), then I cannot reuse input(), as the same set of code in the callback function would be executed everytime I invoke input().I did go through the document you referred and tried some of them but didn't satisfy my requirement.This may be dumb but I seek some help.

Comment: Your original question was "why isn't it going into the if when i type 'quit'?". I answered that question. Then in your comments you ask a new question "How do i achieve synchronous execution without using other packages?" Which is completely different. I answered that question in my edit. And now you are asking a completely new question. One question at a time. For further questions make a new question post and explain your requirements clearly in your initial question and accept the answer that addresses that problem.

Comment: I don't mean to sound harsh, I'm just a little frustrated because I feel like you are adding requirements when a solution is presented.

Comment: Ok @Patrick. Sorry for frustrating you. Can I expect answer for my new requirement or should I start a new thread and share the link???

Comment: I would say, if you feel like your original question was answered, please +1 the answer and mark it as 'solved'. If you have another question, ask it in a separate question. Feel free to send me a link to it via a message or comment here and I can try to solve it if i can.

Answer (score 0):

After you type "quit" you hit enter, so you actually need to match a newline character as well "\n"

Try this instead:

```
if(text == "quit\n") {
  console.log("Inside if"); 
  done();
}
```

By the way, there are some great packages that can help with creating Node CLI apps.

See:

- Inquirer.js https://github.com/SBoudrias/Inquirer.js
- Vorpal https://github.com/dthree/vorpal

Comment: This solution is working.But then this is still behaving asynchronous. As I mentioned earlier, I want a line by line code execution. PFB output

    **deepak@deepak-VirtualBox:~/Desktop$ node test.js  
    Completed 1  
    hey  
    Received: hey  
      
    Received: hey  
  
    quit  
    Inside if  
    Exiting**

I have removed this line of code "console.log("Type: " + typeof text);"
How do I achieve synchronous execution without using other packages??